# Jquery gridster plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

How can i modify this fiddle to get the new items to be added to the right instead of snapping to the bottom...I want the hieght to be fixed and for it to expand for new items to the right

http://jsfiddle.net/maxgalbu/UfyjW

```
var layout;
var grid_size = 100;
var grid_margin = 5;
var block_params = {
max_width: 6,
max_height: 6
};
$(function() {

layout = $('.layouts_grid ul').gridster({
    widget_margins: [grid_margin, grid_margin],
    widget_base_dimensions: [grid_size, grid_size],
    serialize_params: function($w, wgd) {
        return {
            x: wgd.col,
            y: wgd.row,
            width: wgd.size_x,
            height: wgd.size_y,
            id: $($w).attr('data-id'),
            name: $($w).find('.block_name').html(),
        };
    },
    min_rows: block_params.max_height
}).data('gridster');

$('.layout_block').resizable({
    grid: [grid_size + (grid_margin * 2), grid_size + (grid_margin * 2)],
    animate: false,
    minWidth: grid_size,
    minHeight: grid_size,
    containment: '#layouts_grid ul',
    autoHide: true,
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        var resized = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            resizeBlock(resized);
        }, 300);
    }
});

$('.ui-resizable-handle').hover(function() {
    layout.disable();
}, function() {

    layout.enable();
});

function resizeBlock(elmObj) {

    var elmObj = $(elmObj);
    var w = elmObj.width() - grid_size;
    var h = elmObj.height() - grid_size;

    for (var grid_w = 1; w > 0; w -= (grid_size + (grid_margin * 2))) {

        grid_w++;
    }

    for (var grid_h = 1; h > 0; h -= (grid_size + (grid_margin * 2))) {

        grid_h++;
    }

    layout.resize_widget(elmObj, grid_w, grid_h);
}
});​
```

Comment: I would really like to know how to do this to! If you have found a way please let me know